# how to convert &#39 ; to single quote in apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, json, string, javascript-remoting

`Abc&#39;s Place` this coming in apex.
actual picklist value is => `Abc's Place`,

`Abc&#39;s Place` is coming from json from Vf page to Javascript Remoting.

It's throwing an error when I am passing to field, says that Restricted field value. how to convert  `&#39;`  to `'`?

I have used `String.valueOf` and `escapeUnicode`, but no luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`&#39;` is escaped [HTML Entity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity), just like `&#40;`, `&amp;`, and [so on](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html). To unescape most of them in Apex use [String.unescapeHtml4()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm) method which

> Unescapes the characters in a `String` using `HTML 4.0` entities.

For instance:

```
String unescapedString = 'Abc&#39;s Place &amp; Xyz&#39;s Place'.unescapeHtml4();
// "Abc's Place & Xyz's Place"
```

Comment: yes that exactly correct, just found this link too usefull: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AtmvIAC